# evaluate an integration of complicated exponential function

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, exponential-function, improper-integrals

I am trying to evaluate an integration of complicated exponential function that I encountered in my wireless communication research. Can anyone help me with this?
$\int_{\sqrt{x}}^{\infty}\exp{-\left(\frac{x^2+ax}{b}+\frac{c}{x^2-d}\right)} dx$

I tried many approaches and even used online integration calculator; however it seems that the elementary antiderivative does not exist.

Comment: where's the complex here? Did you mean $\frac{c}{x^2-d}i$ ?

Comment: @JohnSmithKyon. I suppose that it means *complicated*

Comment: $x$ is used both in the bounds and as the integration variable, one or the other should be switched to a dummy variable. Or is the lower bound meant to be $\sqrt{d}$?

Comment: @alan devkota I have edited the formatting to make the question more readable. Please confirm my edits are correct.

Comment: @JohnSmithKyon Yes, it's "complicated". Sorry about that.

Comment: @JohnSmithKyon There is no complex.

Comment: Does $\exp- y=\exp(-y)$?

Comment: Even the much simpler integral with $c=0$ is non-elementary. Why do you think there is an elementary solution? Perhaps you are interested in an approximation to the integral for some parameter? In which case you'd need to tell us which parameter and the range you are interested in (eg. as $c \to \infty$)

Comment: I am not sure if the OP is active, but a series representation may work.